# Not Equal Search With LeftJoin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
Select 
    m.name 

from machines m 
    innerJoin config c ON m.cod = c.cod

--> where ( c.category = 'BIOS' and c.val = 'System' )  
--> and   ( c.category = 'Users' and c.val = 'Jonas' )  

group by c.cod

* MACHINES ---------------- +
| key    | name    | cod    |
* ------ + ------- + ------ +
| 1      | M1      | 23     |
| 2      | M2      | 26     |
| 3      | M3      | 27     |
+ ------ + ------- + ------ +

* CONFIG --------------------------- +
| key    | category | cod   | val    |
+ ------ + -------- + ----- + ------ +
| 1      | BIOS     | 23    | System |
| 2      | Users    | 23    | Jonas  |
| 3      | Users    | 23    | Maria  |
| 4      | BIOS     | 26    | System |
| 5      | Users    | 26    | Jonas  |
| 6      | BIOS     | 27    | System |
| 6      | Users    | 27    | Ana    |
+ ------ + -------- + ----- + ------ +
```

i got

```
* RESULT -- +
| name      |
+ --------- +
| M1        |
| M2        |
+ --------- +
```

Its Great for 'Equal' search, but i don't know how i do the 'Not Equal' search for this query.

I tried:

```
Select 
    m.name 

from machines m 
    innerJoin config c ON m.cod = c.cod

--> where ( c.category = 'BIOS' and c.val <> 'System' )  
--> or    ( c.category = 'Users' and c.val <> 'Jonas' )  

group by c.cod
```

but still getting the Machine 'M1', the field with value 'Maria' match with the filter

i need to do with this filter the result:

```
* RESULT -- +
| name      |
+ --------- +
| M3        |
+ --------- +
```

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted query has a repeated mistake in it: `category` and `val` come from table `c`, not `m`.

Then, it seems to me that what you want is to discard those records which refer to a machine for which other records exist with your condition. Unfortunately, this cannot be done with conditions on records alone, so it’s no use negating conditions. You have to do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
  FROM machines 
 WHERE name NOT IN (
     SELECT m.name       
       FROM machines m 
       INNER JOIN config c USING (cod)
      WHERE ( c.category = 'BIOS' AND c.val = 'System' )  
        AND ( c.category = 'Users' AND c.val = 'Jonas' )
 )
```

Comment: It Worked! , now a do not need to use group_concat or having, is that i think, the subquery is inevitable

Comment: It can be done on conditions with a having. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2a480/4/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT name FROM machines 
WHERE name NOT IN (
SELECT m.name FROM machines m    INNER JOIN config c ON m.cod = c.cod WHERE ( c.category = 'BIOS' and c.val = 'System' )  AND ( c.category = 'Users' and c.val = 'Jonas' ) GROUP BY c.cod)
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it’s identical to mine and was posted 3 minutes before, while I was still typing mine... (well, identical... it still has the `m.`-error I pointed out in mine)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
    m.name 

from machines m 
    innerJoin config c ON m.cod = c.cod

where NOT (
( m.category = 'BIOS' and m.val = 'System' )  
 and ( m.category = 'Users' and m.val = 'Jonas' )
) 

group by c.cod
```

Comment: This would still get the unwanted `M1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script :

```
    SELECT M.Name FROM Machines AS M LEFT JOIN CONFIG AS C ON M.Cod=C.Cod 
    WHERE  NOT ( 
    (M.Category ='BIOS' AND M.Val='System') AND
    (M.Category ='Users' AND M.Val='Jonas') 
    )
```

`NOT` keyword is easy solution for your query. i also did left join instead inner, you can ignore it if not require.

Comment: This would still get th unwanted `M1` (and it is identical with LONG’s answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Working SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2a480/4/1)

Since you need the paired value to have 2 records for the system I'd use this for the equal

This does assume that a category/cod/val is unique in Config.

```
SELECT m.name
FROM machines m
INNER JOIN config c
  on c.cod = m.cod
WHERE (( c.category = 'BIOS' and c.val = 'System' )  
   OR ( c.category = 'Users' and c.val = 'Jonas' ))
GROUP BY m.name
having count(*) =2 ;
```

and this for the not equal...  note the 2 simply changes if you have a more "OR" critiera

```
SELECT m.name
FROM machines m
INNER JOIN config c
  on c.cod = m.cod
WHERE (( c.category = 'BIOS' and c.val = 'System' )  
   OR ( c.category = 'Users' and c.val = 'Jonas' ))
GROUP BY m.name
having count(*) <>2 ;
```